# Horizontal ListBox unable to scroll Windows Phone 8.1 WP8.1

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I'm having a problem with `ListBox` in my WP8.1 application (WinRT), I'm unable to make it scroll horizontally. 5 images fit the screen and everything after 6th is simply cropped.
I tried adding `ScrollViewer` around listbox, around `ItemsPanelTemplate` for `ListBox` and nothing works.
This is my xaml code

```
    <ListBox x:Name="AppBarMenu"
         Grid.Row="1"
         Canvas.ZIndex="1"
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColorApp}"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StackMenuItem}"
         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
         Style="{StaticResource ListBoxHorizontal}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxContainerStylePP}"
         Foreground="{StaticResource TBColorNonSelected}"
         SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=PetProtectorFrames, Mode=TwoWay}"
         Height="0"
         VerticalAlignment="Top"
         SelectionChanged="AppBarMenu_SelectionChanged"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">

     </ListBox>
```

And this is a template for `ItemsPanelTemplate`

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxHorizontal"
       TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I event tried adding `VirtualizationStackpanel` instead of stack panel as ItemsPanemTemplate but it acts the same. And when I try to set the property `CanHorizontallyScroll=true`, I get two errors, first is that this property doesn't exist inside `VirtualizationStackpanel`, and after deleting this property and returning it again, I get the error `Syntax Error found in XBF generation`.
I tried searching a solution for this by myself, looked here, googled it but I couldn't find the solution. Can someone help me with this? I'm busting my head with it for 2 days.

UPDATE:

The listbox is inside grid with folowing setup:

```
    <Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.091*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.01*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="0.9*" />

    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The second row height is set to auto because I'm animating listbox height. Listbox acts as AppBar, when I press button on app bar, listbox shows up containing menu items.

SOLUTION UPDATE:

Inspired by the solution provided by  SWilko, I also managed to solve my problem with little more configuration of my 'ListBox', so a fix to my previous code looks like this:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="AppBarMenu"
     Grid.Row="1"
     Canvas.ZIndex="1"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
     ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
     Background="{StaticResource BackgroundColorApp}"
     ItemTemplate="{StaticResource StackMenuItem}"
     ItemsSource="{Binding}"
     Style="{StaticResource ListBoxHorizontal}"
     ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxContainerStylePP}"
     Foreground="{StaticResource TBColorNonSelected}"
     SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, ElementName=PetProtectorFrames, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Height="0"
     VerticalAlignment="Top"
     SelectionChanged="AppBarMenu_SelectionChanged">

 </ListBox>
```

All that should be done is to disable vertical scrolling and enable horizontal one.

Comment: can you post the rest of the xaml ie the `Grid` or panels around the `ListBox'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is the Height of your ListBox is set to 0 but presume that might be typo :)

Here's a simple example of `ListBox` scrolling horizontally.

Item.cs

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs constructor

```
public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.NavigationCacheMode = NavigationCacheMode.Required;

        var list = new List<Item>
        {
            new Item { Name = "Item 1" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 2" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 3" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 4" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 5" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 6" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 7" },
            new Item { Name = "Item 8" }
        };

        this.AppBarMenu.ItemsSource = list;
    }
```

MainPage.xaml

```
 <Grid>
    <ScrollViewer
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
    ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
    ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled">
        <ListBox x:Name="AppBarMenu"
            ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
            ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                 Height="100"
            VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="Red" 
                           FontSize="30"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Note `ListBox` scrollviewer is disabled and `ScrollViewer` is wrapped around it.
Hopefully you can adapt for your code

Comment: Hi, I'll try it when I get home and I'll post results :) from this point, I'd say that it might work, because I never tried to disable ScrollViewer inside listbox... And, it is not a typo, on first load I need the menu(listbox) to be "hidden". So when I press the button it "shows up" with animation :) thanks! :)

Comment: @Shakal187 yes its quite a common procedure to use a wrapping `ScrollViewer` rather than the `ListBox` one due to unpredictable behaviour. Good luck

Comment: I tried your solution and it works like a charm :) Thank you very much! As you can propbably guess, I'm still a newbee in wp8.1 programming, but I'm striving to be an experienced developer for wp8.1. Also, I tried to "setup" ListBox's 'ScrollViewer' the same as you did with wrapping 'ScrollViewer'. I'll update my questioon for that example also, for others who come across this question. Once again, Thank you very much!